# Escape spaces in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to do something in a bash script whenever a file in a directory I am iterating over contains a string using `grep`.  The problem comes in where a subset of the files in the directory contain spaces in the name.  Therefore, I have tried to replace the spaces with escaped spaces in place using `sed`:

```
if grep -c "main" ${source} | sed 's/ /\\ /g'; then
  # do something
fi
```

However, I still get the error:

> grep: /Users/me/Desktop/theDir/nameWith: No such file or directory
>
> grep: spaces.txt: No such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `grep -c` does not print anything on output that has spaces. Hint: It's a number. You probably meant `grep -l`

Comment: the grep is just the if conditional to check if the file contains `"main"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should quote the name of the file being grep'ed:

```
if grep -c main "$source" ; then
  # do something
fi
```

...assuming `$source` is the name of a file. If `$source` is the name of a directory, I'll need more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Oh, now I understood what OP was trying to do with `sed` :D. I thought OP actually wanted to pass `grep` output to `sed`

Comment: @anishsane I'm still not 100% sure what OP is trying to do, but I figured I'd start with this suggestion and see how it goes. :)

Comment: Yes, this looks like the correct interpretation of the actual problem. I think this answer should solve OP's problem.

Comment: for full disclosure  `$source` is actually a file path so any directory in the path could also have spaces but your answer applies to that case as well.  i was unaware of what enclosing a variable in quotes does and it seems it did the trick.

Comment: For more details on quoting, see [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) and [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) link...